# ¿Cómo adquirió "rajar" el significado de "hablar mucho"?

Tags: etimología, significado, historia, coloquialismos

De acuerdo al RAE  una de las acepciones coloquiales de "[rajar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=V4yGPQZ)" es

> 7. intr. coloq. Hablar mucho.

Entre algunas de las otras acepciones se incluyen

> 6. intr. coloq. Decir o contar muchas mentiras,
> 7. intr. Bol., Col., Ec., Méx., Perú y Ven. Hablar mal de alguien, desacreditarlo.

que tienen también cierta relación con "hablar". Los significados no coloquiales de este verbo son "Dividir en rajas; Hender, partir, abrir".

¿Cómo ha llegado "rajar" a adquirir el significado coloquial de "hablar mucho"?

Comment: Interesante pregunta. También espero por la respuesta. Confirmo que en Colombia lo usamos cuando alguien esta hablando mal de otro. Ej. "Pedro no hace sino **rajar** de Juan" = (Pedro vive hablando mal de Juan)

Comment: Pues si os digo que el verbo "rajar" aparece en el diccionario de Covarrubias de 1611 con el significado de "decir muchas mentiras"...

Comment: Todas esas acepciones son completamente desusadas en Argentina.

Answer (score 3):

Aquí en Sevilla se usa "rajar" para decir que una persona habla mucho, sobre todo con ánimo de criticar, como afirma la acepción 7 en el diccionario. Puede que estemos ante una palabra que se exportara desde España hasta América en el siglo XVI dado que ya aparece en el diccionario de Covarrubias de 1611, por lo que debía de usarse desde bastante antes.

Covarrubias explica que "raja" era como se denominaba a la astilla de madera:

> RAJA. La astilla que se parte con el [destral](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DUifeAM) del madero, para que con más facilidad arda en el fuego, como las rajas de la leña [...].

A partir de este significado deduce Covarrubias el que nos ocupa:

> Por alusión llamamos rajar, cuando alguno dice muchas mentiras en razón de su valentía.

Vamos, que "rajar" se decía de aquel que se jactaba de valiente pero no hacía más que contar trolas. No me queda clara cuál es la "alusión" que menciona Covarrubias, en todo caso. El significado original se ve en textos del siglo XV en los que se habla de "escudos rajados" (astillados), o de "herir la puerta y rajarla" y cosas así. Entiendo entonces que golpear escudos con fuerza y rajarlos era actividad común en combate, y que fuese algo que los jactanciosos mencionasen durante sus bravatas.

Su uso se atestigua en el siglo XVI:

> *"Soltadle -les gritó- de tal baraja
>
>   presto, si no queréis que os dé la muerte."
>
>   "¿Quién es este tan fiero que así raja?"
>
>   -dijo uno por mostrarse de más fuerte-.*
>
> Jerónimo de Urrea, "Traducción de 'Orlando furioso' de Ludovico Ariosto", 1549 (España).

Otro ejemplo anterior:

> *Jacinto: Dexa rajar al fragoso,
>
>   que ya trahe la lengua suelta.*
>
> Anónimo, "La Comedia Ypólita", 1521 (España).

Corominas determina el origen de *rajar* en el siglo XV, no muy anterior a estos ejemplos, y dice que "es muy posible que *rajar* resulte de un cruce de *rachar* con su sinónimo *ajar*, que también significó *rajar*". Cierto es que en el siglo XV encontramos textos que hablan de "el escudo fecho rachas". E incluso hay textos del siguiente porte:

> *[...] mas yo vos digo que todo aquel que se ensaña con su proximo, sera digno de juyzio. E el que dixiere a su proximo racha: sera digno de consejo.*
>
> Gonzalo García de Santa María, "Evangelios e epístolas con sus exposiciones en romance", a1485 (España).

El propio texto aclara más adelante que en este caso *racha* significa "menosprecio", sin embargo nos encontramos que la antecesora de *raja* ya tenía su versión figurada.

Comment: Curioso. Coincido con que en España también se usa como "hablar mucho" o como "hablar mal". La conexión con los otros no la veo muy clara. Yo siempre pensé que se debía a inutilizar la "cremallera" que se usa con el significado de "callarse". Si, aunque te hubieras puesto cremallera, se raja la bolsa, sale todo el contenido.